# Neural net from floating point to interger weights

Tags: c, neural-network

I've made a simple program that uses a neural network with floating point weights in C. Now I want to use int8_t or int16_t weights, how should I change the code? The training is a problematic part with integers.

Here is the simple example:

This part is the net definition

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef double NNType;
// numer of inputs
#define IN 2
// number neurons layer hidden
#define HID 8
// numer of outputs
#define OUT 1
// learning constant
#define EPS 0.1

NNType input[IN]; // input
NNType hidden[HID]; // layer hidden
NNType output[OUT]; // output
NNType weightH[HID][IN]; // weights layer hidden
NNType biasesH[HID]; // biases layer hidden
NNType weightO[OUT][HID]; // weights output
NNType biasesO[OUT]; // biases output
```

This part is the network calculation and the training part

```
inline NNType Activation(NNType x)
{
   return x>0?x:0;
}

inline NNType Derivative(NNType x)
{
   return x>0?1:0;
}

NNType NetworkResult(NNType inp1,NNType inp2)
{
   // load the inputs
   input[0]=inp1;
   input[1]=inp2;
   // compute hidden layer
   for (int i=0;i<HID;i++)
   {
      hidden[i]=biasesH[i];
      for (int j=0;j<IN;j++)
         hidden[i] += input[j]*weightH[i][j];
      hidden[i]=Activation(hidden[i]);
   }
   // compute output
   for (int i=0;i<OUT;i++)
   {
      output[i]=biasesO[i];
      for (int j=0;j<HID;j++)
         output[i] += hidden[j]*weightO[i][j];
      output[i]=Activation(output[i]);
   }
   return output[0];
}

void TrainNet(NNType inp1,NNType inp2,NNType result)
{
   NetworkResult(inp1,inp2);
   NNType DeltaO[OUT];
   NNType DeltaH[HID];
   // layer output
   NNType err= result-output[0];
   DeltaO[0]=err*Derivative(output[0]);
   // layer hidden
   for (int i=0;i<HID;i++)
   {
      NNType err=0;
      for (int j=0;j<OUT;j++)
         err+= DeltaO[j]*weightO[j][i];
      DeltaH[i]=err*Derivative(hidden[i]);
   }
   // change weights
   // layer output
   for (int i=0;i<OUT;i++)
   {
      for (int j=0;j<HID;j++)
         weightO[i][j]+=EPS*DeltaO[i]*hidden[j];
      biasesO[i]+=EPS*DeltaO[i];
   }
   // layer hidden
   for (int i=0;i<HID;i++)
   {
      for (int j=0;j<IN;j++)
         weightH[i][j]+=EPS*DeltaH[i]*input[j];
      biasesH[i]+=EPS*DeltaH[i];
   }
}
```

This is the main of the program that trains the net to learn an xor operation

```
// constant for weights initializations
#define CONSTINIT 0.1

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   srand(1);
   // initalize weights and biases
   for (int i=0;i<HID;i++)
   {
      for (int j=0;j<IN;j++)
         weightH[i][j]= 2.0 * ( (rand()/((NNType)RAND_MAX)) - 0.5 ) * CONSTINIT;
      biasesH[i]=0.1;
   }
   for (int i=0;i<OUT;i++)
   {
      for (int j=0;j<HID;j++)
         weightO[i][j]= 2.0 * ( (rand()/((NNType)RAND_MAX)) - 0.5 ) * CONSTINIT;
      biasesO[i]=0.1;
   }
   // calculate the results with the random weights
   printf("0 0 = %f\n",NetworkResult(0,0));
   printf("0 1 = %f\n",NetworkResult(0,1));
   printf("1 0 = %f\n",NetworkResult(1,0));
   printf("1 1 = %f\n",NetworkResult(1,1));
   printf("\n");
   // Train the net to recognize an xor operation
   for (int i=0;i<1000;i++)
   {
      TrainNet(0,0,0); // input 0 0 result 0
      TrainNet(0,1,1); // input 0 1 result 1
      TrainNet(1,0,1); // input 1 0 result 1
      TrainNet(1,1,0); // input 1 1 result 0
   }
   // calculate the results after the train
   printf("0 0 = %f\n",NetworkResult(0,0));
   printf("0 1 = %f\n",NetworkResult(0,1));
   printf("1 0 = %f\n",NetworkResult(1,0));
   printf("1 1 = %f\n",NetworkResult(1,1));
   printf("\n");
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: While you certainly could use ints to represent a fixed point value in the range +-1, you probable don't want to.  While your simple(classic) XOR example would train with 8 bit representations, anything more complex may experience issues. One of the enabling technologies of recent NN use is the cost of cheap microprocessors that can do at least 64bit floating point because it is useful to have that much dynamic range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now I want to use int8_t or int16_t weights, how should I change the code? The training is a problematic part with integers.

Code uses floating point to keep values in the range of [-1.0 ... 1.0].

Moving directly to integer types only gives 3 values -1,0,1.  With integers,  I'd expect you would want to use a *scaling*.  With `int8_t`, maybe [-64...64].  Each time code uses `*`, the product needs to be scaled.

```
// input[j] * weightH[i][j]
input[j] * weightH[i][j] / 64;
```

Select addition/subtraction need tests to detect overflow.

---

What looks easy with floating point, becomes tricky (although maybe faster) with integers.
Some untested code for just the random number part.

```
// weightH[i][j]= 2.0 * ( (rand()/((NNType)RAND_MAX)) - 0.5 ) * CONSTINIT;
 
// Break CONSTINIT into even numerator/denominator parts.
// Map [0...RAND_MAX] to [-64 ... 64]* CONSTINIT
#define scale_up (2LL*(64 - -64 + 1)*CONSTINIT_NUMERATOR)
#define scale_dn (2LL*RAND_MAX*CONSTINIT_DENOMINATOR)
long long r = scale_up*rand() - scale_up*RAND_MAX/2;
// add proper signed one-half divisor
r += (r < 0) ? -scale_dn/2 : scale_dn/2;
weightH[i][j]= r/scale_dn;  // scale down
```

Answer (score 0):

> I've made a simple program that uses a neural network with floating point weights in C. Now I want to use int8_t or int16_t weights, how should I change the code? The training is a problematic part with integers.

I do not understand why the training would be problematic and I think you've meant that it is problematic with floats.

Anyways, what I would like to suggest is that you do not use integers over floating points for your neural network operation. You see, by the nature of mathematical operations performed during using or training the network it must be implemented using floats (or doubles). Otherwise you would loose information from  the fractional part.

Of course, using integers is possible. After all a float x.yy is going to be an integer when multiplied by 100 but it would be an overkill to implement as everything would have to be shifted this way.